# Getting all keys and their values from ObjectStateEntry in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, audit, ef-database-first

For audit logging purpose I override `SaveChanges()` method in EF 4.1 Database-First approach .

I have all ObjectStateEntry object and I'm wondering if I could get all keys and their values from each ObjectStateEntry .

```
   IEnumerable<ObjectStateEntry> changes = this.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Deleted | EntityState.Modified);
    foreach (ObjectStateEntry stateEntryEntity in changes)
    {
        if (!stateEntryEntity.IsRelationship &&
                stateEntryEntity.Entity != null &&
                    !(stateEntryEntity.Entity is DBAudit))
        {
          list<object , object> KeyValues = GetAllKeyValues(stateEntryEntity );
          //Do log all keyvalues
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't tested it but something like this should work:

```
private Dictionary<string, object> GetAllKeyValues(ObjectStateEntry entry)
{
    var keyValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    var currentValues = entry.CurrentValues;
    for (int i = 0; i < currentValues.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        keyValues.Add(currentValues.GetName(i), currentValues.GetValue(i));
    }
    return keyValues;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , Is there any way i could retrieve just primary and foreign keys ?

Comment: @Mostafa, long overdue but I have a solution that may be suitable.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69825846/414655

Answer (score 3):

Try using [`ObjectStateEntry.EntityKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstateentry.entitykey.aspx) and [`EntityKey.EntityKeyValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entitykey.entitykeyvalues.aspx):

```
var keyValues = stateEntityEntry.EntityKey.EntityKeyValues;
```

which returns an array of [EntityKeyMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entitykeymember.aspx).  You can then use the `Key` and `Value` properties, which return a `string` and `object` respectively.

Comment: Both EntityKey and EntityKeyValues are null so it return null all the time

Comment: @Mostafa, sorry, I'm not sure why you are getting `null` for those properties.  I just tried code similar to yours, but using a `DbContext`.  The only thing I needed to do was call `ChangeTracker.DetectChanges()` on the `DbContext`, and after doing that it did get key values using `EntityKey.EntityKeyValues`.

Comment: I suppose you are testing with Self-Tracing Entity Generator , Because i have not ChangeTracker method on my objectContext

Comment: Hello I am running into the same issue where I get null for those properties. I have tried calling ChangeTracker.Detectchanges() but could not get the key values. Is there any other possibility?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution in the form of an extension method.

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> GetKeyValues(this ObjectStateEntry instance)
    {
        var keyMemberNames = instance
            .EntitySet
            .ElementType
            .KeyMembers
            .Select(x => x.Name)
            .ToList();

        var currentValues = instance.CurrentValues;
        var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        for (var i = 0; i < currentValues.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            var name = currentValues.GetName(i);
            if (!keyMemberNames.Contains(name))
                continue;

            var value = currentValues.GetValue(i);
            result.Add(name, value);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static IReadOnlyDictionary<string, object> GetValues(this ObjectStateEntry instance)
    {
        var currentValues = instance.CurrentValues;
        var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        for (var i = 0; i < currentValues.FieldCount; i++)
        {
            var name = currentValues.GetName(i);
            var value = currentValues.GetValue(i);
            result.Add(name, value);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```